# SAS into TERADATA timestamp formatting

Tags: sql, sas, timestamp, teradata, varchar

I need to convert these SAS lines of code into Teradata.
Most specifically, the new field to be created, a timestamp, derives from a `DES_OEA_VALUE` varchar(1024) variable, which has dates in it like `'14-JAN-2019'` and `'31-DEC-2018'`, but as well `'095545689090756'` or `'a#f34!65+612n2%24n5'` or addresses and ecc. ecc.

```
SELECT 20200528 AS NMR, COD_IBA, CASE WHEN DES_OEA_VALUE IS NOT NULL AND DATEPART(t1.TMS_OST_EXPIRY_ENT - dhms(INPUT(t1.DES_OEA_VALUE,date11.), 0, 0, input('00.00.00.000001', time10.))) <= 365 AND DATEPART(t1.TMS_OST_EXPIRY_ENT - dhms(INPUT( t1.DES_OEA_VALUE,date11.), 0, 0, input('00.00.00.000001', time10.))) > 0 THEN 'B'
    WHEN DES_OEA_VALUE IS NOT NULL AND DATEPART(t1.TMS_OST_EXPIRY_ENT - dhms(INPUT(t1.DES_OEA_VALUE,date11.), 0, 0, input('00.00.00.000001', time10.))) > 365 THEN 'C'
    WHEN DES_OEA_VALUE IS NULL AND DATEPART(t1.TMS_OST_EXPIRY_ENT - t1.TMS_OST_EFFECTIVE) = 0 THEN '99' END AS CASES FROM T1
```

I tried some solutions and advices, but no the outcome is not good yet.
It should be a timestamp resulting of the concatenation of the dates in DES_OEA_VALUE + '00.00.00 000001'

Hope I can get helped

Comment: Does this single variable store multiple data types? Are you running this in SAS?

Comment: How does SAS handle the bad data? You could extract the date parts using a RegEx, rearrange it into a proper YYYY-MM-DD format and the TRYCAST (which sadly doesnt't support FORMATs). Of course, you will need a CASE to catch the different input formats and matching RegEx for all of them.

Comment: Is there another column that indicates whether the values in `DES_OEA_VALUE` are a date or something else?

Comment: @StuSztukowski... well... it's not me to having executed the sas jobs, what i need to do is to convert sas data in teradata...

Comment: @andrew, actually yes, I just found it out... there is a column which tells me what kind of dataype is inside

Comment: If it's always the same format `Cast(DES_OEA_VALUE  AS TIMESTAMP FORMAT 'dd-mmm-yyyy') + INTERVAL '0.000001' SECOND`. Btw, why do you add that microsecond?

Comment: @Enrico, if you have a column that tells you the type, you can just wrap @Dnoeth's answer in a case statement - `case when <column tells you it's a timestamp> then Cast(DES_OEA_VALUE AS TIMESTAMP FORMAT 'dd-mmm-yyyy') + INTERVAL '0.000001' SECOND else ...end`.

Comment: @Enrico Just curious, but do you have the ability to connect SAS to Teradata? SAS and Teradata are deeply integrated. You could then load it from SAS to Teradata on the SAS side, and it might resolve some of these issues. You'd be able to do the logic you need in the data step rather than SQL.